# DIV Class Nested in Section Class not setting to display: flex

Tags: flexbox, display

I am trying to learn CSS, and find myself stuck.  I am hoping you can help.

I have created a section and I want this to be a flex container.  I have nested divs in the section for each item I want to display in the container.  I have added a class to both the section and the parent div, but I cannot get the display: flex property to apply to the div.  When I inspect in Chrome as I have it now it reflects display: block.  If I try to select the div.class it will not style.  Thanks!

HTML:

```
<section class="headline">
    <div class="Details">
        <div>
            <h4>headline 1</h4>
            <p>some content included.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>headline 2</h4>
            <p>some more content.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>headline 3</h4>
            <p>more content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>headline 4</h4>
            <p>end content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



    .headline {
color: white;
background-color: black;
display: flex;
```

}

```
.details {
display: flex;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the class .Details was in the html with a capital d and in the stylesheet with a lower case d. :)